# How to add new line between attributes using org.w3c.dom. xml in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am creating xml file using org.w3c.dom and javax.xml.parsers in JAVA. But its giving me result something like below:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:esv="http://eresources.nlb.gov.sg/ID/NLBDM/vocab-esv/" xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" xmlns:nlbdm="http://eresources.nlb.gov.sg/ID/NLBDM/vocab/" xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
</rdf:RDF>
```

What I need is to put the attributes with proper tabbed indentation in new line each of them. It should be like below:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:esv="http://eresources.nlb.gov.sg/ID/NLBDM/vocab-esv/"
    xmlns:nlbdm="http://eresources.nlb.gov.sg/ID/NLBDM/vocab/">
</rdf:RDF>
```

I found couple of same question on Stackoverflow as well, but in answer they had suggested to change the xml parser, that I don't want to do. Can I do the same thing using my existing xml parser? I don't think ,such minor issue they might have not handled.

Below is a part of my code:

```
// write the content into xml file
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

String tempFileName=file.getName();
tempFileName=tempFileName.substring(0,tempFileName.indexOf("."));

StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:/Users/Pratik/MapArticleURIWithNER/"+tempFileName+".rdf"));

// Output to console for testing
//StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

transformer.transform(source, result);

//System.out.println("File saved!");
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any tool for serializing XML that gives you this amount of control over the exact layout of the result. Why do you care? The extra whitespace might be visually attractive, but no sane XML-consuming application will behave differently depending on how much whitespace there is between attributes.

(Well, I say that, but I noticed another question this morning that was trying to process XML using sed or awk. That falls outside my definition of a sane XML-consuming application...)